# Dirac measure cannot be induced by a continuous PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $\delta_0: [-1,1]
> \to\mathbb{R}$ with $\delta_{0}(E) := 1$, if $0 \in E$ and $\delta_{0}(E) := 0$ if $0 \notin E$ be the Dirac measure at $0$. Prove that there is no continuous probability density function, such that $\delta_0$ is the induced probability measure of $f$.

From the definition of the Dirac measure it seems obvious, that $f$ must be defined as $f(x) = 1$, if $x = 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise, which is not a continuous function and also $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)dx = 0$, since $f = 0$ almost everywhere (w.r.t the Lebesgue measure). This concludes the proof. However, I'm a little unhappy with just *assuming* that $f$ has to be defined like I claimed above. Is there a cleaner way to go about this step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that saying "it must be defined like this" then showing your definition doesn't make sense is not correct. :)

This is a straightforward application of Lebesgue differentiation theorem. If there was a function $f(x)$, then the function:

$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(x) dx=\chi_{x\geq 0}$$ would be differentiable almost everywhere (it is) and $F'(x)=f(x)$ a.e. However $\chi'_{x\geq 0}=0$ a.e. which is not a PDF.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, avid. Maybe I should have added that my definition of $f$ came from considering the singleton sets and observing, that $\delta_0(\{0\}) = 1$. Anyways, why is this integral equal to the indicator function on the positive reals?

Comment: @jazzinsilhouette It's just the definition of of a PDF. $F(x)=P(-\infty,x]$ This is $0$ for $x<0$ and $1$ for $x\geq 0$.

Comment: @jazzinsilhouette https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Absolutely_continuous_univariate_distributions

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the definition. I was confused because I didn't realise that you already applied the definition of the Dirac measure to get the result.